# How do I produce a number with absolute precision of some power of 10?

Tags: vb.net, decimal

Vb.net has a decimal data type.

Unlike normal double or floating points, decimal data type can store values like 0.1

Now say I have a variable like precision.

Say precision is 8

So basically I want to do

```
Protected Overridable Sub setPairsPricesStep2(decimalPrecission As Long, Optional base As String = "", Optional quote As String = "")
    If decimalPrecission = 8 Then
        Return
    End If
    Dim price = 10D ^ (-decimalPrecission)
    setPairsPriceStep1(price, base, quote)
End Sub
```

There is a problem there

the result of Dim price = 10D ^ (-decimalPrecission) is double, not decimal. I can convert it to decimal but then I will lost the precission.

So what is the right way to do it? Should I just use for next but that's hardly elegant.

It's simple

I want a function that given precisions give decimal value.

For example, if precision is 1 I got 0.1. If precision is 5, I got 0.00001

I ended up doing this

```
For i = 1 To decimalPrecission
    price *= 0.1D
Next
```

But surely there is a better way

Update:

Per comment, I tried

```
Dim e = 10D ^ -5
Dim e1 = 10D ^ -5L
```

The type of e and e1 are both double.

I suppose I can do Cdec(e). But then it means I have lost accuracy because normal double cannot store .1 correctly.

Comment: Think the issue is related to Explicit vs Implicit type declarations.  Pretty sure you will find Dim price As Decimal = 10D ^ (-decimalPrecission) will do what you need

Comment: Isn't, e.g., `Dim price = CDec(10D ^ -5L)` returning `0.00001`? What are you losing?

Comment: Can you explain the notation? What is 5L?  Also if we have a double that is latter converted to decimal, wouldn't that means losing accuracy?

Comment: I think there is a website on how a floating/single/double number is represented. I wonder where

Comment: You have `decimalPrecission As Long`. That what `5L` is: `5` declared as Type Long. `CDec(10D ^ -5L)` is `0.00001`. Replace `5L` (`e.g.` translates to *for example*) with the value of `decimalPrecision` (just 1 `s`. I know, pedantic)

Comment: The documenation for the [^ Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/exponentiation-operator) states "The result is number raised to the power of exponent, always as a Double value." Additionally, Math.Pow doesn't have an overload that takes two Decimals and returns a Decimal. So, your loop looks like a good way to do it. You could construct a string and use Decimal.Parse on it, but I suspect that would be a lot slower than the loop (you can of course try it out if you want).

Answer (score 1):

> I want a function that given precisions give decimal value.
>
> For example, if precision is 1 I got 0.1. If precision is 5, I got 0.00001

Since you are working with the Decimal type, the simplest way to get this result is to use the [Decimal constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Decimal__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Boolean_System_Byte_) that allows you to specify the scale factor.

> Public Sub New (lo As Integer, mid As Integer, hi As Integer, isNegative As Boolean, scale As Byte)

From the Remarks section of the above referenced documentation,

> The binary representation of a Decimal number consists of a 1-bit sign, a 96-bit integer number, and a scaling factor used to divide the integer number and specify what portion of it is a decimal fraction. The scaling factor is implicitly the number 10 raised to an exponent ranging from 0 to 28.

So you can see that if take the value of one divided by 10 to the first power, the result is 0.1.  Likewise, one divided by 10 to the fifth power, the result is 0.00001.

The lo, mid, and hi arguments in the constructor could be obtained by uisng the [Decimal.GetBits Method](Decimal.GetBits Method), but for this simple case, I chose to hard code the values for the value of one stored as a decimal.

To obtain a value of 0.1D:

```
New Decimal(1, 0, 0, False, 1)
```

To obtain a value of 0.00001D:

```
New Decimal(1, 0, 0, False, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim stringrepresentation = "1E-" + decimalPrecission.ToString
    Dim price = Decimal.Parse(stringrepresentation, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowExponent)
```

This is what I basically did. Basically I created a string 1E-5, for example, and use decimal.parse to get the decimal

I wonder if there is a better way but I have no idea.

Actually Jimy ways may work too but rounded to a number